# Init DictionaryLiteral without data

Tags: swift, dictionary

I would like to init a Swift DictionaryLiteral object without any data.

Such as:

```
var withoutData: DictionaryLiteral = [String: [RealmObject]]()
```

However, this is creates the error `Cannot convert value of type '[String : [RealmObject]]' to specified type 'DictionaryLiteral'`

But if I do the same thing with data directly, it works:

```
var withData: DictionaryLiteral = ["test": [RealmObject()]]
```

What's the reason behind it?
And how to declare an empty variable DictionaryLiteral?

Comment: Why would you want to use `DictionaryLiteral`? Why not simply use `Dictionary`?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I need the dictionary to be ordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: `DictionaryLiteral` is now deprecated.  Use `KeyValuePairs` instead.

---

In your first example, you are creating a `Dictionary` and then trying to initialize a `DictionaryLiteral` with it.  They are two different types, hence the error.  You can use `()` to create the `DictionaryLiteral`, but you must correctly specify the type you are creating. A `DictionaryLiteral` using a `String` as the key and `[RealmObject]` as the value is specified by `DictionaryLiteral<String, [RealmObject]>`.

In your second example, you are providing an actual dictionary literal, so Swift is able to infer the type as `DictionaryLiteral<String, [RealmObject]>`.  No `Dictionary` is actually ever created.

So one way to create an empty `DictionaryLiteral` is to fully specify the type when creating it and let Swift infer the variable type:

Current syntax:

```
var withoutData = KeyValuePairs<String, [RealmObject]>()
```

Old Swift syntax:

```
var withoutData = DictionaryLiteral<String, [RealmObject]>()
```

The other way is to fully specify the data type of the variable and then initialize the variable with an empty dictionary literal `[:]` as [JonJ shows in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53170673/1630618).

Answer (score 2):

```
var withoutData: DictionaryLiteral<String, [RealmObject]> = [:]
```

Comment: But my Value is an array

Comment: Actually wether it is an array or not, this init is not authorized by Xcode apparently. I'm using XCode 10 (Swift 4.2). `Error: Expected '>' to complete generic argument list`

Comment: Sorry, typo. The items are separated by a comma in the list of arguments. Now fixed.